# How to add glow to star background

Tags: node-editor

I have these nodes set up, emulating a starry night sky. is these some way I can sort of give them a more lighting up glow effect?

[image]

Comment: have you tried the Bloom effect in Eevee and/or the Glare node in the Compositor?

Comment: Yes I've got the bloom effect checked on EEVEE .This is going to be an animation not static image. So I'm not knowledgeful if the compositor would work for what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: yes, compositor also works for animations.

Comment: Yep, it worked for me, thanks.

Comment: you can also animate the Strength value of some stars Emission node if you want them to shine more or less along the timeline

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using Eevee bloom, you can get this kind of result:

[image]

This is tuned using 4 parts:

- Densify the colorramp setting black and white close to each other
- Grow the background strength (eg 50)
- Play with the bloom radius
- Grow bloom intensity above its limits (set the value manually), for instance to 2

Comment: This is a intuitive way to achieve the effect using the nodes set up. Thanks for the screen shot, very useful!!!